# Getting "permission denied" when deploying Firebase project

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cli

I have a simple Angular project working fine on local server, but when I try to deploy it to firebase with `firebase deploy --debug` I get the error:

```
database: checking rules syntax...
[2018-07-14T12:39:49.428Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://fir-demo-project.firebaseio.com/.settings/rules.json?dryRun=true
 {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
 Sat Jul 14 2018 15:39:49 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))
[2018-07-14T12:39:50.236Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 401 server=nginx, date=Sat, 14 Jul 2018 12:39:49 GMT, content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8, content-length=36, connection=c
lose, access-control-allow-origin=*, cache-control=no-cache, strict-transport-security=max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload
[201

8-07-14T12:39:50.237Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY {
  "error" : "Permission denied"
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All though I Deselected "Database: Deploy Firebase Realtime Database Rules" there is still was a database.rules.json file for some reason, but turns out that was not the cause of problem, probably deploy failed because I had some rubbish in .firebaserc file. I had some other project inside :

```
"projects": {
    "ConB": "fir-demo-project",
    "default": "concrete-2e0f7",
    "concrete": "concrete-2e0f7"
  }
```

So I changed it to :

```
"projects": {
    "ConB": "concrete-2e0f7",
    "default": "concrete-2e0f7",
    "concrete": "concrete-2e0f7"
  }
```

And now it deploying.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just didn't have Owner access to the app. You can see it at the FB console: "View only" icon and a label at the top right corner.
Try to request Owner access at the app's Owner.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced exactly the same problem. I had previously defined my own rules in the firebase console, but they were overwritten by the deploy.

After I overwrote the file `database.rules.json` in the root directory of the Angular application with my own rules, there were no more problems after a redeploy.

Example for `database.rules.json`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        // Allow only authenticated content owners access to their data
        ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    },
    "products":{
      ".write": "root.child('users').child('role').val() === 'admin'"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and this is how I fixed it.

1. run firebase init
2. Deselect ❯◯ Database: Deploy Firebase Realtime
   Database Rules
3. Go through other steps to setup the initial app,
   selecting the default for each should work just fine. run firebase
   serve

Hope that helps